# Deriving Generic types with fewer arguments in python 3

Tags: python, generics, typing

I have code where I define a generic class with two type variables:

```
Selected = ty.TypeVar('Selected')
SelectionIDs = ty.TypeVar('SelectionIDs')
class GenericSelection(col.UserDict, ty.Mapping[SelectionIDs, Selected]):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
```

Then I want to derive a subclass of the previous generic class in which I want to specify one of the type variables as a sequence of integers (an index in this case).

```
class IndexedSelection(GenericSelection[int, Selected]):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
```

Then I want to define Selected type variable to be a specific type of object, say `str`, which according to the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#user-defined-generic-types) and [PEP 483](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0483/#defining-and-using-generic-types) this is allowed.

```
class StrSelection(IndexedSelection[str]):
    def __init__(self, strings: ty.Sequence[str], sel: ty.Sequence[int]):
        super().__init__()
        for sel_idx in sel:
            self[sel_idx] = strings[sel_idx]
```

However, I get the error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
/home/salotz/Dropbox/tutorials/python_types/typing_class.py in <module>()
     47         super().__init__()
     48 
---> 49 class StrSelection(IndexedSelection[str]):
     50     def __init__(self, strings: ty.Sequence[str], sel: ty.Sequence[int]):
     51         super().__init__()

/home/salotz/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/typing.py in __getitem__(self, params)
    968             if len(params) != len(self.__parameters__):
    969                 raise TypeError("Cannot change parameter count from %d to %d" %
--> 970                                 (len(self.__parameters__), len(params)))
    971             for new, old in zip(params, self.__parameters__):
    972                 if isinstance(old, TypeVar):

TypeError: Cannot change parameter count from 2 to 1
```

Maybe I'm misunderstanding the role of the Generic type, as there isn't a whole lot of examples around. Am I missing something to get this to work?

Comment: This works with the current versioon of mypy. It was probably not fully supported at the time you tried it.